# What are the problems that causes neural networks stagnate in learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I was trying to see how accurate a neural network can approximate simple functions, like a scalar-valued polynomial in several variables. So I had these ideas:

1. Fix a polynomial of several variables, say, f(x_1,..,x_n).
2. Generate 50000 vectors of length n using numpy.random which will serve as training data.
3. Evaluate the f(x) at these points, the value will be used as label.
4. Make test data and label in the same way
5. Write a neural network and see how accuracy it can approximate f(x) on test set.

Here is my sample neural network implemented in tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_vector_length = int(10) 
output_vector_length = int(1)
train_data_size = int(50000)
test_data_size = int(10000)
train_input_domain = [-10, 10]  #Each component in an input vector is between -10 and 10
test_input_domain = [-10, 10]
iterations = 20000
batch_size = 200
regularizer = 0.01
sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_vector_length], name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape =[None, output_vector_length], name="y")

function = tf.reduce_sum(x, 1) + 0.25*tf.pow(tf.reduce_sum(x,1), 2) + 0.025*tf.pow(tf.reduce_sum(x,1), 3)

#make train data input
train_input = (train_input_domain[1]-train_input_domain[0])*np.random.rand(train_data_size, input_vector_length) + train_input_domain[0]

#make train data label
train_label = sess.run(function, feed_dict = {x : train_input})
train_label = train_label.reshape(train_data_size, output_vector_length)

#make test data input
test_input = (test_input_domain[1]-test_input_domain[0])*np.random.rand(test_data_size, input_vector_length) + test_input_domain[0]

#make test data label
test_label = sess.run(function, feed_dict = {x : test_input})
test_label = test_label.reshape(test_data_size, output_vector_length)

def weight_variables(shape, name):
    initial = 10*tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variables(shape, name):
    initial = 10*tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def take_this_batch(data, batch_index=[]):
    A = []
    for i in range(len(batch_index)):
        A.append(data[i])
    return A

W_0 = weight_variables(shape=[input_vector_length, 10], name="W_0")
B_0 = bias_variables(shape=[10], name="W_0")
y_1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W_0) + B_0)


W_1 = weight_variables(shape=[10, 20], name="W_1")
B_1 = bias_variables(shape=[20], name="B_1")
y_2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(y_1, W_1) + B_1)

W_2 = weight_variables(shape=[20,40], name="W_2")
B_2 = bias_variables(shape=[40], name="B_2")
y_3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(y_2, W_2) + B_2)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")
y_drop = tf.nn.dropout(y_3, keep_prob)

W_output = weight_variables(shape=[40, output_vector_length], name="W_output")
B_output = bias_variables(shape=[output_vector_length], name="B_output")
y_output = tf.matmul(y_drop, W_output) + B_output


weight_sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W_0)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W_1)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W_2)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(W_3))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_output)) + regularizer*(weight_sum)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
error = cost

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
with sess.as_default():
    for step in range(iterations):
        batch_index = np.random.randint(low=0, high=train_data_size, size=batch_size)
        batch_input = take_this_batch(train_input, batch_index)
        batch_label = take_this_batch(train_label, batch_index)
        train_step.run(feed_dict = {x : batch_input, y:batch_label, keep_prob:0.5})
        if step % 1000 == 0:
            current_error = error.eval(feed_dict = {x:batch_input, y:batch_label, keep_prob:1.0})
            print("step %d, Current error is %f" % (step,current_error))


    print(error.eval(feed_dict={x:test_input, y:test_label, keep_prob:1.0}))
```

Simply speaking, the performance of this neural network is horrifying! My neural network has three hidden layers of size 10, 20 and 40. The input layer is of size 10, and the output layer has size 1. I used a simple L^2 cost function, and I regularized it with the square of weights and regularizer 0.01.

During training stage, I noticed that the error seems to get stuck and refuses to go down. I am wondering what could go wrong? Thanks a lot for reading this long question. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Everything can go wrong. When using non-linearities, this is a nonconvex-optimization problem. This is infeasible in general (with current knowledge) so there is no guarantee to converge to a global-optimum. Even more depressing: SGD-based algorithms only guarantee local-optimal convergence for some parameter-chosings of learning-rate/learning-decay (SGD was developed for convex opt). I'm pretty sure you can prove that there exist some nn-arch + param-settings for some given problem where you obtain the information-theor. optimum, but choosing these hyper-params is not well understood.

Comment: In fact, my neural performed okay on small intervals. For example, if I generate both training set and testing set on the interval [-1, 1], the error is acceptable, something like, 0.02. However, if I enlarge the interval to [-10, 10], the error is going to be ridiculous. Is this a typical feature of neural network, i.e. it has reasonable performance if the data is restricted in some sense.

Comment: That's probably because NNs love standardized data (there is theoretical reasoning!). Normalize mean and variance. That's not necessarily a feature of NNs, but of Gradients, Backpropagation and SGD.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem

Comment: Also, http://stats.stackexchange.com is better suited for machine learning questions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sigmoid as the activation function in the hidden layers, the value at these neurons is reduced to the range of (0,1). Hence, it is a good idea to normalize the input data for this network.